# acer aspire es 15 windows 10 usb 3.0 not working out the box

Tags: windows-10, usb-3, acer-aspire

So I recently brought this laptop and havnt had any issues with it expect the usb 3.0 working. I can use 3.0 devices in the 2.0 slots but then I don't get the speed that I want. I have ran a unbuntu live cd and the usb 3.0 works fine in that. So my next idea was try to reinstall the driver that didn't work (btw the driver it uses is for windows 7?) Wouldn't install at all, on the Acer website there are some drivers I think it was the chips set one that when I reinstalled got my usb working aging but still no usb 3.0? I have totally reinstalled windows still no success any help guys?

Ps I rang up acer and they tryed to tell me that my laptop has no usb 3.0 and all they could offer was to take it away and fix it leaving me without my laptop for however long it takes them to try and sort it.

The support site offered me 10%off my next perchance from them but fat chance I'll ever use that.

Comment: **Warning** - please do not use obscenities in your posts. I've removed it for you. Note that other users may have flagged your post as "rude or abusive" leading to possible rep loss or suspension. Please read [Be Nice](http://superuser.com/help/be-nice): "Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive"

Comment: Sorry about that new here